# Repeat character in Fish Shell

Tags: repeat, fish

I find myself needing to print repeated characters to terminal output in my scripts, so I get lines like:
`=========================`

`*************************`

`+++++++++++++++++++++++++`

How do I easily get this output in Fish Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function underline -a char -a length
    printf '%*s\n' $length "" | tr ' ' $char
end
underline = 8
```

```
========
```

This takes advantage of printf's variable length formatting, and the default field padding of spaces.

Comment: +1 for named arguments. A solution with a pipe to tr seems inelegant to me though.

Answer (score 3):

I need this so often I ended up writing a very simple function `do_str` that repeats a given string a given number of times.

Pasting the code below in your config.fish (and reloading the shell) will be sufficient:

```sh
function do_str #defines the function, you can use any other name for it
  for i in (seq $argv[2]) #starts a for loop that will repeat as many times as second argument given
    printf $argv[1] #prints the first argument given (the string)
  end
end
```

Running `do_str = 4` produces `====`, `do_str "?.!" 4` produces `?.!?.!?.!?.!?.!`

**NB** If you need to print percent signs, you must escape double percent signs **AND** escape the first percent sign, so to get `%%%%%%` you must call `do_str \%% 6`

Comment: If you use `printf "%s" $argv[1]`, you don't have to double the percent (although you do still have to escape it from fish, or quote it: `do_str '%' 6`)

Answer (score 3):

The `seq` command is made for such things:

```
$ seq -f '' -s= 20
====================

$ seq -f '' -s+ 20
++++++++++++++++++++

$ seq -f '' -s+ 5
+++++
```

But attention:

There is no newline character after the string.
You can use the `-t` flag to add it:

```
$ seq -f '' -s+ -t\n 5
+++++
```

Comment: It fails because `-f` doesn't have a `%s`: "seq: format ‘%s’ has unknown %s directive"

Answer (score 3):

In Fish 3:

```
string repeat -n80 +
```

Where `-n` is the number of times that it has to be repeated and `+` is the string to be repeated.